# NTLM or Kerberos for Intranet & Internet application in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, authentication, kerberos, ntlm

NTLM or Kerberos.... which authentication is suitable for

1. Intranet application?
2. Internet application?

### Will answer differ if 3rd party tools are used?

for MySite and ContentType Hub application which authentication should we follow?

if any web application has Form Based authentication NTLM or Kerberos which one will be correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Kerberos for an Internet-facing system (as users cannot receive a ticket from the KDC), however you should use Kerberos for Intranet-facing systems when possible as it is faster as well as more secure.

Comment: for

MySite

and

ContentType Hub

which authentication should we follow?
if any web application has Form Based authentication NTLM or Kerberos which one will be correct approach?

Comment: MySites and ContentType Hubs are just site collections and follow the protocol in place for the webapplication.  With FBA you can't use Kerberos unless you have a third party (UAG, NetScaler, BigIP, etc) that can delegate credentials.

Answer (score 2):

If users will never be connecting to backend system for intranet (using BCS) then NTLM suitable. Kerberos solves double hop issue, so Kerberos usually necessary if passing credentials if not using Secure Store Services.

There is no ONE solution here. Honestly, your environment and needs for data integration will hold your answer.

Comment: if Secure Store Services is used for BCS then NTLM is OK for intranet? Trevor seward said different.

Comment: Kerberos is **not** required for Secure Store Services in intranet environment.  In fact, Secure Store Services is one of the double-hop solutions in a NTLM environment. And when Secure Store Services can be used I am, typically, in favor.

Trevor is exactly correct, however, in saying that Secure Store Services cannot be used in internet-facing environment because users cannot authenticate to AD.  I am not sure about anonymous authentication with Secure Store as I have never tested.  But I would generally say stay away from anonymous access to your secured data anyway.